# Google API PHP Client: How do I pull the changed events between calendars using the sync token?

Tags: google-api-php-client

Just to specify, I want to do this using the Google Client PHP API found [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

I've just imported all of a calendars events into my personal website. Now I want to synchronize events that I may have added to my calendar on Google. Optimally this would happen on page load - I'd check my last sync token, compare it with the current sync token, and this would give me a list of changed events.

Am I thinking about this wrong? This is what I'm trying to do:

```
// grab all of my events that have changed from the sync token provided
// to the current sync token now

$event_list = $service->events->listEvents('my_calendar_id');
$event_list->setNextSyncToken('my_old_calendar_sync_token);
```

All this is doing is overriding the sync token retrieved from the first request. Reading the API document [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync), there's a snippet of code specified in Java that shows the sync token being set before the request is executed, which is likely the issue.

I even tried something like:

```
$event_list = $service->events
    ->listEvents('my_calendar_id')
    ->setNextSyncToken('my_old_calendar_sync_token);
```

(Curious to see if setting them on the same line would be interpreted in the request)

Although it's not through the API I'm referring to, the documentation does specify this is possibly through this GET request:

```
GET /calendars/primary/events?maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&syncToken=CPDAlvWDx70CEPDAlvWDx
```

How can I achieve the same results through the Google API PHP Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It's in an additional options array passed into listEvents found inside the code if you dig around a bit:

```
$event_list = $service->events->listEvents('my_calendar_id', ['syncToken' => 'my_old_calendar_sync_token']);
```

Comment: Nice find; it literally took me quite a few hours to figure this out :(

Comment: Was the difference that the first form retrieves all the events and then refreshes to just what the syncToken would have provided? Just asking because it wasn’t clear. Obviously we don’t want to read the events twice (even only if the first page).